# Using simple C header file definitions in C# application

Tags: c#, c++, header-files

I have a somewhat difficult problem with rewriting a C++ application into C#. Basically the C++ application includes a C header file that contains structure and enum definitions:

Imagine it like this:

Header file:

```
/**********  myHeader.h *************/

#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HEADER_H

#define MY_CONSTANT    10u
#define OTHER_CONSTANT 20u


typedef enum 
{
  ACTION_ONE,
  ACTION_TWO,
  NUMBER_OF_ACTIONS
} myEnum;


typedef struct
{
  uint32_t member;
  uint32_t bitfield_msb : 24;
  uint32_t bitfield_lsb : 8;
} myStruct;

#endif
```

So currently the C++ program references these structures. It gets the format from the .h file and constructs structures based on this data. The header itself is also included in a C project. This ensures the compatibility between two projects as they both use identical data structures.

Can anybody recommend a good way of implementing this in C#? Or is it mission impossible. Ofcourse I could define the structures separately in C# format, but in that case the connection between the C project and the (C++ to be translated to C# project) would be lost.

Comment: There are no header-files in C#. However I don´t understand why you care for them if you want to rewrite your logic in C# anyway.

Comment: You would need to define explicit layout structure to make sure you can marshal between them. And this only works for primitive types, structures which also have an explicit layout and char arrays, but for the last one you need to define size and format and such.

Comment: @HimBromBeere If I understand it correctly, the OP needs to maintain layout compatibility with the structures as they are used (and presumably evolved) in a C application.